# Unity3D: Want multiplayer/networking. How do I handle socket exceptions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I want to setup multiplayer in Unity. I failed to connect to the master server when using Unity's built-in networking, so I tried the Photon Unity Networking plugin instead. I still can't connect so I think I'm missing something. All of the demos give the same error, but I don't understand what the problem is and can't find a fix online.

The error I get when trying to connect is:

> Receive issue. State: Connected Exception:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x00000] in
>   :0 at ExitGames.Client.Photon.SocketUdp.ReceiveLoop
>   () [0x00000] in :0
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   PhotonHandler:DebugReturn(DebugLevel, String) (at Assets/Photon Unity
>   Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:153)
>   NetworkingPeer:DebugReturn(DebugLevel, String) (at Assets/Photon Unity
>   Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:934)
>   ExitGames.Client.Photon.<>c__DisplayClass2:b__0()
>   ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
>   ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
>   PhotonHandler:Update() (at Assets/Photon Unity
>   Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:76)

My scene is simple. This is the line trying to connect:

```
PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("v0.1");
```

I'm on Mac using Unity 4.3.2f1, with a Unity Pro license. I've disabled my firewall. Any help in understanding this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No experience in using Photon. But as you said you failed to connect to your server with various methods. Is the server actually running? Can you verify it by simply using `telnet` or `ping` or w/e tools?